# How to create a scrollable content in react-native that can cover up fixed content elements?

Tags: react-native

Imagine a layout where you have a fixed button top-right of the screen.

The content is wrapped in a some card-like component.

The user an scroll up now so that the content covers the whole screen and moves over the fixed button on top-right.

I tried:

- Using a scrollview and try `pointerEvents="box-none"` on the scrollview itself and set marginTop on the `contentContainerStyle` so that the fixed button is still visible. Looks correct, but you can't click the button
- Using a Scrollview that starts after the header that contains the button and set overflow: visible. While this looks correct, you can't scroll the card outside of the area of the scrollview. Additionaly, you can still click on the covered button

Somehow i would need a scrollview where the pointer events are only considered when they happened on the visible scrollable content.

Any idea how to solve this problem?